# How can I make a right-click menu to open with a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to figure out how I can make a tab, in which I can edit with my own ide that I made in python tkinter. Is there a library of some sorts; I can use to do it, or its something built-in the register system of windows, linux, and mac? If so please leave the source code down below as a comment or a answer, Thanks for the help! :)

[image: Here is the default example in windows]

### My whole code for the ide

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- encoding: utf8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        #### Tkinter Settings
        self.title(f"untitled")
        self.geometry('668x673')
        
        #### File Menu
        FileMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        FileMenu.add_command(label="New File", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+N")
        FileMenu.add_command(label="Open...", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+O")
        FileMenu.add_command(label="Open Module...", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+M")
        Submenu = tk.Menu(FileMenu, tearoff=False)
        FileMenu.add_cascade(label="Recent Files", menu=Submenu)
        FileMenu.add_command(label="Module Browser", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+C")
        FileMenu.add_command(label="Path Browser", underline=0)
        FileMenu.add_separator()
        FileMenu.add_command(label="Save", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+S")
        FileMenu.add_command(label="Save As...", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+Shift+S")
        FileMenu.add_command(label="Save Copy As...", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+Shift+S")
        FileMenu.add_separator()
        FileMenu.add_command(label="Print Window", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+P")
        FileMenu.add_separator()
        FileMenu.add_command(label="Close", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+F4", command=self.destroy)
        FileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+Q", command=self.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=FileMenu, underline=0)

        #### Edit Menu
        EditMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Undo", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+Z")
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Redo", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+Shift+Z")
        EditMenu.add_separator()
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Cut", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+X")
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Copy", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+C")
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Paste", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+V")
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Select All", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+A")
        EditMenu.add_separator()
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Find...", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+F")
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Find Again", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+G")
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Find Selection", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+F3")
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Find in Files...", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+F3")
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Replace", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+H")
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Go to Line", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+G")
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Show Completions", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+space")
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Expand Word", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+/")
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Show Call Tip", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+backslash")
        EditMenu.add_command(label="Show Surrounding Parens", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+0")        
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=EditMenu, underline=0)

        #### Format Menu
        FormatMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        FormatMenu.add_command(label="Format Paragraph", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+Q")
        FormatMenu.add_command(label="Ident Region", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+]")
        FormatMenu.add_command(label="Dedent Region", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+[")
        FormatMenu.add_command(label="Comment Out Region", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+3")
        FormatMenu.add_command(label="Uncomment Region", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+4")
        FormatMenu.add_command(label="Tabify Region", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+5")
        FormatMenu.add_command(label="Untabify Region", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+6")
        FormatMenu.add_command(label="Toggle Tabs", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+T")
        FormatMenu.add_command(label="New Indent Width", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+U")
        FormatMenu.add_command(label="Strip Trailing Whitespace", underline=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Format", menu=FormatMenu, underline=0)

        #### Run Menu
        RunMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        RunMenu.add_command(label="Run Module", underline=0, accelerator="F5")
        RunMenu.add_command(label="Run Customization", underline=0, accelerator="Shift+F5")
        RunMenu.add_command(label="Check Module", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+X")
        RunMenu.add_command(label="Python Shell", underline=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Run", menu=RunMenu, underline=0)

        #### Options Menu
        OptionsMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        OptionsMenu.add_command(label="Configure IDLE", underline=0)
        OptionsMenu.add_separator()
        OptionsMenu.add_command(label="Show Code Context", underline=0)
        OptionsMenu.add_command(label="Show Line Numbers", underline=0)
        OptionsMenu.add_command(label="Zoom Height", underline=0, accelerator="Alt+2")
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=OptionsMenu, underline=0)

        #### Window Menu
        WindowMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        OptionsMenu.add_command(label="Configure IDLE", underline=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Window", menu=WindowMenu, underline=0)
        
        #### Help Menu
        HelpMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        HelpMenu.add_command(label="About IDLE", underline=0)
        HelpMenu.add_separator()
        HelpMenu.add_command(label="IDLE help", underline=0)
        HelpMenu.add_command(label="Python Docs", underline=0, accelerator="F1")
        HelpMenu.add_command(label="Turtle Demo", underline=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=HelpMenu, underline=0)
        self.config(menu=menubar)
            
        #### UserInput Handler
        self.text_entry = tk.Text(self, height=80, width=10)
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.text_entry.yview)
        self.text_entry.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill="y")
        self.text_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill="x", expand=True)

        ### Right Click
        self.RightClick = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.RightClick.add_command(label="Cut", command=lambda: self.text_entry.event_generate('<Control-x>'))
        self.RightClick.add_command(label="Copy", command=lambda: self.text_entry.event_generate('<Control-c>'))
        self.RightClick.add_command(label="Paste", state="disabled")
        self.RightClick.add_separator()
        self.RightClick.add_command(label="Set Breakpoint")
        self.RightClick.add_command(label="Clear Breakpoint")            
        self.bind("<Button-3>", self.right_click)

        
    def right_click(self, event):
        try:
            self.RightClick.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
        finally:
            self.RightClick.grab_release()
    

                    
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    app = MainApplication()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you're trying to build a real app, you should throw Tkinter into the trash can right now, and investigate one of the REAL frameworks, like Qt or wxWidgets.  Tkinter works for small projects, but it is a 40-year-old library that doesn't scale.

Comment: I think first you should add functionality to your open button, right now it appears your app has no way of opening a file?

Comment: @TimRoberts: tkinter is a real framework, perfectly suited for many tasks. I've made commercial applications with it, and an IDE is not particularly large scale.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You mention making a "tab" but you aren't using a Notebook widget. Are you asking how to use the Notebook widget?

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/add-any-application-to-right-click-menu-in-windows-10 Is this what you want, at least for Windows? Are you trying to do this programatically with a python library? I don't understand.